# Signup form: email and submit on the same

Tags: php, html, css

At the bottom of [my site](https://kendozone.com), I have a sign up form. I can't make the button to be on the same line and close to that the email.

It already has a class assigned, so it's just about the css, but I'm no expert on css :(

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="mc4wp-form-fields"><h1 align="center">
  Want to hear updates on the future releases?
</h1><br>
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" class="signup" required="">
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="signup_button">
```

Any Idea how to do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input has a width of 100% - therefore taking 100% of the container.

```
input[type="email"] { width:/*something thats not 100%*/ }
```

Comment: you rock! Do you know how should I correct the one pixel vertical alignment that fail???

Answer (score 0):

You could float them, providing neither is set to 100% width...

```
 <input style="float:left;"  type="email" name="EMAIL" ....
 <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Sign up" ....
```